# Javascript undefined variable issue in IE 9

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I get the following error in IE9 other browsers and even IE 9 compatibility view works perfectly...

```
SCRIPT5009: 'Entry1_Ctrl1_ctl01_txtDate1' is undefined
```

I have the following JavaScript in asp.net page;

```
string script = "javascript:return popUpCalendar(this," + 
                       _CalendarCtrl1.ClientID + @", 
                      'mm/dd/yyyy', '__doPostBack(\'" + 
                      _CalendarCtrl1.ClientID + @"\'),')";
```

this is how its rendered;

```
onclick="javascript:return popUpCalendar(this,Entry1_Ctrl1_ctl01_txtDate1, 'mm/dd/yyyy', '__doPostBack(\'Entry1_Ctrl1_ctl01_txtDate1\'),')"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems obvious enough: the (ugly) variable `Entry1_Ctrl1_ctl01_txtDate1` is not defined at that point in the script.

Comment: ASP.NET renders these ugly names. The actual name is "txtDate1". I used JQuery $("#txtDate1") to make it work.